# JS: Promise returned from Async function firing early

Tags: javascript

I created a few functions that contain Promises and tried chaining them.  Everything works as expected

```
function foo1() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         setTimeout(() => {
           console.log("11111") 
           resolve()
         }, 4000);
     }).then(() => {
          console.log("222222")
     })
}
```

---

```
function foo2() {
     new Promise(resolve => {
           setTimeout(() => {
               console.log("3333")
               resolve()
           }, 3000)
     })
}
```

---

```
foo1().then(() => foo2())

// "1111"
// "2222"
// "3333"
```

If I put the same thing an async/await, it works as expected too:

---

```
async function testAsync() {
    let one   = await foo1();
    let two   = await foo2();
}

// "1111"
// "2222"
// "3333"
```

I know that async functions return a Promise so I tried the following:

```
testAsync().then(() => {
     console.log("FINISHED");
})
```

but the result was:

```
// "1111"
// "2222"
// "FINISHED"
// "3333"
```

Why would `"FINISHED"` execute ahead of `"3333"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foo2` function returns no Promise, just returns undefined.

That's why you're seeing "FINISHED" before "3333"

If `foo2` looks like below, it will work as you want.

```js
function foo2() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("3333")
            resolve()
        }, 3000)
    })
}
```

Comment: thank you.  Doesn't an async function inherently return a Promise though? why would `foo2` need to return a Promise if nothing is chained in there?

Comment: Even though you attach `async` in front of `foo2`, `foo2` will return `fulfilled Promise` which returns immediately. So, the result will be the same. You should return `pending Promise`.